# Соединить две окружности. В чём ошибка?

Tags: javascript, svg, vector, геометрия, 2d

Пытаюсь повторить полигон, тот что изображен зеленой линией на рисунке ниже. Пользовался этими советами:

[Совет первый](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2043054/find-a-point-on-a-perpendicular-line-a-given-distance-from-another-point) 
[Совет второй](https://answers.unity.com/questions/564166/how-to-find-perpendicular-line-in-2d.html)

Оба дают результат с некоторым смещением вдоль окружностей.
Помогите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка.

[Jsfiddle проект](https://jsfiddle.net/artemy/4ehjn3t8/5/)

Писал на JS, но подойдёт любое другое решение.
Даже без кода, в чистой теории, в чем неверен мой подход.

[image: a busy cat]

```
//
```

Comment: у вас вроде есть угол альфа наклона исходного вектора. Есть радиусы окружностей. Вы не можете просто из центров кругов отложить 4 вектора радиусов r и R, с углами перпендикулярными (альфа+90, альфа-90) исходному?

Comment: Вторая картинка тоже неверная! Касательные не опираются на общий диаметр (перпендикулярный отрезку, соединяющему центры), если радиусы разные. Попробую описать подход.

Comment: @MBo там скорее использование термина "касательные" неверное. Видно что на желаемом полигоне, прямые пересекают большую окружность.

Comment: @teran Мне кажется, что истинные касательные в подобных задачах имеют больше смысла, поэтому на них ориентируюсь

Comment: @MBo можете сколь угодно смысла придумывать себе, автор пишет, что ему надо реализовать вторую картинку. там явно видно что это не касательные, и что углы перпендикулярны. Но задача именно в этом, а не касательных, как опрометчиво написано в заголовке.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4ehjn3t8/6/ такое вам надо? но это не касательные вовсе

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, за время. Мир не без добрых людей! Затруднялся с опредлением этих линий, как их назвать. Вероятно буду использовать оба решения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поскольку нужны только внешние касательные (могут быть ещё внутренние), то подход может быть не слишком сложным:

Пусть центр большей окружности `CR`, меньшей `cr`. Вектор разности `d`, его длина и нормализованный вектор:

```
 d = cr - CR
 dlen = length(d)
 ud = d / dlen
```

Общие касательные к окружностям разного радиуса пересекаются где-то в точке `OP`. Касательная вместе с радиусами к точкам касания образует два подобных прямоугольных треугольника (поскольку радиус перпендикулярен касательной). Из подобия следует

```
Coeff = R / (R - r)
OP = CR + d * Coeff
```

Синус и косинус угла `A` этого треугольника

```
ca = R / (dlen * Coeff)
sa = Sqrt(1-ca*ca)
```

Точки касания большой окружности могут быть получена поворотом вектора `ud*R` на `A` и `-A`

```
P.x = CR.x + ca * R * ud.x + sa * R * ud.y
P.y = CR.y - sa * R * ud.x + ca * R * ud.y
Q.x = CR.x + ca * R * ud.x - sa * R * ud.y
Q.y = CR.y + sa * R * ud.x + ca * R * ud.y
```

Аналогично для малой окружности с использованием её центра и радиуса.

Тест:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aek3xvtL/):  (подправил последовательность точек и знаки углов)

```
let c1 = this.state.circles[0];
let c2 = this.state.circles[1];

let l = getVectorLen(c1,c2);

let v = {x: c2.x-c1.x, y: c2.y-c1.y};
let uv = {x: v.x / l, y: v.y / l};

let ca = (c2.r - c1.r) / l;
let sa = Math.sqrt(1 - ca*ca);

let ps = [

    c1.x - ca * c1.r * uv.x - sa * c1.r * uv.y, 
    c1.y + sa * c1.r * uv.x - ca * c1.r * uv.y,
    c1.x - ca * c1.r * uv.x + sa * c1.r * uv.y,
    c1.y - sa * c1.r * uv.x - ca * c1.r * uv.y,

    c2.x - ca * c2.r * uv.x + sa * c2.r * uv.y,
    c2.y - sa * c2.r * uv.x - ca * c2.r * uv.y, 
    c2.x - ca * c2.r * uv.x - sa * c2.r * uv.y, 
    c2.y + sa * c2.r * uv.x - ca * c2.r * uv.y 
];
```

Comment: Еще раз большое спасибо! Получился отличный обучающий материал.

Answer (score 1):

На картинке 2 из вашего вопроса имеется две окружности с центрами в точках `c1` и `c2` радиусов `r1` и `r2`. Центры окружностей соединены прямой. Необходимо в каждой окружности провести 2 диаметра перпендикулярных отрезку, соединяющему центры. Точки пересечений диаметров с окружностью образуют искомый четырехугольник (трапецию).

```
circles: [
        { r: 20, x: 50, y: 150, f: 'black'},   // c1
        { r: 50, x: 150, y: 100, f: 'black'}   // c2
    ]
```

Для решения необходимо определить угол `alpha` между вектором `c1c2` и осью Х. После чего будет понятно, под каким углом проходят диаметры. Нам потребуется поставить 4 точки, каждая из которых будет удалена от центра на расстояние радиуса под углом `alpha + 90` или `alpha - 90`.

Как известно, тангенс угла в прямоугольном треугольнике равен отношению длины противолежащего катета к прилежащему. Так что угол `alpha` достаточно просто вычисляется с помощью формулы (не рассматриваем ситуацию когда `x1=x2`):

```
let alpha = Math.atan( (c2.y - c1.y) / (c2.x-c1.x) );
```

Если нам известна исходная точка `(x0, y0)`, и нам надо сдвинуться на расстояние `R` под углом `a`, то координаты новой точки будут иметь вид `x1 = x0 + R*Cos(a)` и `y1 = y0 + R*Sin(a)`.
В данном случае `R` будет принимать значения `r1` и `r2` (радиусов окружностей), а угол с поворотом на 90 градусов -  `alpha + PI/2` и `alpha - PI/2`.

В исходном виде формула для вычисления координат первой точки будет иметь вид

```
x1 = c1.x + Math.cos(alpha + Math.PI/2)*c1.r;
y1 = c1.y + Math.sin(alpha + Math.PI/2)*c1.r;
```

Для второй - то же самое с углом `alpha - Math.PI/2`. Затем аналогичные равенства для окружности `c2`.

Вспомнив [тригонометрические формулы приведения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) (про углы `α ± π/2` и `-α`) все эти вычисления сводятся к следующему:

```
let cosA = Math.cos(alpha);
let sinA = Math.sin(alpha);

let ps = [
    c1.x - sinA*c1.r, // x1 
    c1.y + cosA*c1.r, // y1    
    c1.x + sinA*c1.r, // x2 
    c1.y - cosA*c1.r, // y2

    c2.x + sinA*c2.r, // x3 
    c2.y - cosA*c2.r, // y3
    c2.x - sinA*c2.r, // x4 
    c2.y + cosA*c2.r, // y4        
];
```

[jsfidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ehjn3t8/8/)

Comment: В данном случае тригонометрический подход ведёт к излишним вычислениям. Углы не требуются - если использовать единичный вектор uv из моего поста, то перпендикуляр к нему будет `(-uv.y, uv.x)` и первая точка `c1.x - uv.y*c1.r,  c1.y + uv.x*c1.r` и т.д.